# NumPy: load heterogenous columns of data from list of strings

Tags: python, load, numpy

I'm working with array data stored in an ASCII file (similar to [this thread](http://thread.gmane.org/gmane.comp.python.numeric.general/42342)). My file is at least 2M lines (158 MB), and is divided into multiple sections with different schemas. In my module to read the format, I want to read the whole file via `lines = open('myfile.txt', 'r').readlines()`, so I can index the positions of each section, then read each section that I need into NumPy data structures.

For example, one excerpt of a section is:

```
>>> print lines[5:10]
['      1 0.1000 0.300E-03 0.000E+00 0.300E-03 0.000E+00 0.000E+00 0.300E-03 0.100E-03\n', 
'      2 0.1000 0.120E-02 0.000E+00 0.120E-02 0.000E+00 0.000E+00 0.120E-02 0.100E-03\n', 
'      3 0.1000 0.100E-02 0.000E+00 0.100E-02 0.000E+00 0.000E+00 0.100E-02 0.100E-03\n', 
'      4 0.1000 0.110E-02 0.000E+00 0.110E-02 0.000E+00 0.000E+00 0.110E-02 0.100E-03\n', 
'      5 0.1000 0.700E-03 0.000E+00 0.700E-03 0.000E+00 0.000E+00 0.700E-03 0.100E-03\n']
```

Which has the schema `[int, float, float, float, float, float, float, float, float]`, and a later part will have have a simpler `[int, float]` schema:

```
>>> print lines[20:25]
['       1         0.00000E+00\n',
'       2         0.43927E-07\n',
'       3         0.44006E-07\n',
'       4         0.44020E-07\n',
'       5         0.44039E-07\n']
```

How can I quickly load in different sections of the lines with NumPy? I see there is `np.loadtxt`, but it requires a file handle, and reads all the way to the end. I also see `np.from*` functions, but I'm not sure how to use them with my already read `lines`. Do I need to read the file twice?

With regards to the heterogeneous data types, I figure I can use a compound `dtype`, like `np.dtype([('col1', '<i2'), ('col2', 'f4'), ('col3', 'f4'), ('col4', 'f4'), ('col5', 'f4'), ('col6', 'f4'), ('col7', 'f4'), ('col8', 'f4'), ('col9', 'f4')])`, correct?

Answer (score 3):

[`StringIO`](http://docs.python.org/release/2.6.4/library/stringio.html) can make file-type objects from strings. So you could do

```
from StringIO import StringIO
m = np.loadtxt(StringIO('\n'.join(lines[5:10])))
```

Or even easier, just do

```
m = np.fromiter(lines[5:10],np.dtype([('col1', '<i2'), ('col2', 'f4'), ('col3', 'f4')]))
```

Comment: I was getting a related `MemoryError` with the string `join` of a few million lines. So instead, I'm feeding my readline file input to a `StringIO` buffer to pass on to `np.loadtxt` (I need to pre-process the input via readline to find relevant sections). All great tips, thanks!

Comment: Note: the `np.fromiter` example does not work as expected, for unknown reasons.